# Divide by zero error encountered when using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got the below piece of code in my query:

```
CAST(COUNT(C.DateChanged) * 100.0 / COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate) AS numeric(18, 2)) AS PBTSbutActived
```

Both fields are of DateTime datatype. The problem is that when I include group by the above piece of code throws this error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

I've read some threads here and tried using this:

```
CAST(COUNT(NULLIF(C.DateChanged, 0)) * 100.0 / COUNT(NULLIF(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate, 0)) AS numeric(18, 2)) AS PBTSbutActived
```

However, it didn't help, I still get the same issue as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NULLIF()` goes *outside* the `COUNT()`:

```
CAST(COUNT(C.DateChanged) * 100.0 /
           NULLIF(COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate), 0) AS numeric(18, 2)
    ) AS PBTSbutActived
```

That is, you need to check the *result* of the `COUNT()`, not the column being counted.

Comment: It worked! I'll keep that in mind. Thanks Gordon, it's not the first time that you save me!

Answer (score 0):

If COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate) is 0, you can not avoid that error. You should add a HAVING clause to your query:

```
CAST(COUNT(C.DateChanged) * 100.0 /
       NULLIF(COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate), 0) AS numeric(18, 2)
) AS PBTSbutActived FROM .... GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using a case statement,

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate) <>0 then 
CAST(COUNT(C.DateChanged) * 100.0 / COUNT(A.LastPassedBackToSalesDate) AS numeric(18, 2)) 
ELSE NULL END AS PBTSbutActived
```